# I block almost every analytics traffic on my browser. Am I depriving myself in any way?

Tags: filtering

I have a web traffic filter installed on my browser. I see that it is constantly blocking mostly analytics related connections. Am I depriving myself in any way? and more importantly, am I protecting myself in any substantial manner?

Answer (score 1):

You gain little and lose a little. Your gains will come from the slight increase in browser and network performance due to the decrease in network traffic (almost nothing). You lose a little because advertisers may not be able to serve content to you that targets your interests. The site provider also loses the ability to provide content you are interested in.

Analytics are a tool for the provider of the site you are using though such information gets passed around to others, too. It helps them see who is interested in their content to, hopefully, provide more and better of that while eliminating the less interesting (including advertising).

It does you no harm and there is no reason to block it other than what the internet crazies will bring up.

Comment: Your answer was spot on...until you said "internet crazies".

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm sorry if I offended you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking specifically about analytics, you don't lose much, though there is a subtle issue. Content owners use analytics to guide their decisions on what to publish and the site visitors are in essence voting with their clicks. If you're blocking analytics, your clicks will not be counted. This can be an issue if the group that has blocking enabled is somehow different from the whole audience, say, they're more technologically sophisticated. The site owner might not realize that their analytics don't represent the full range of visitors.

Another problem can be sites that break if the analytics are blocked. This can be intentional, but is usually just an oversight by the developer. It's common when sites are using advanced analytics features to track, say, form progress and with analytics disabled you might get errors in the console when trying to submit it.

Other than that, there probably isn't a big difference. Now, it's a completely different story with ads, but I shouldn't get into that lest I get branded as an internet crazy.